# Some users appends .blend files with wrong "dowload" linked image

Tags: discussion

[image]

Is there a way to correct this minor typo?

eg:
[Can't get the right camera settings that match the scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40124/cant-get-the-right-camera-settings-that-match-the-scene)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you link the question?

Comment: I just linked it in the text above

Comment: Oh, I completely missed the apparent typo pointed to by the huge arrow and label.

Comment: I can't believe we could have possibly missed that for so long, especially @david, Mr. anti-spam!

Comment: Apparently, in the same mental state that got the "n" left out, I also managed to lose the .psd file. Hopefully I will have a new one soon.

Comment: ... OO did you really use a PSD??? :D

Comment: o.O *How* did we all miss this for so long? (@GiantCowFilms are you sure no one had unauthorized access to the repo or something? :P)

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm pretty confident the mistake was always there. The main reason that if someone had changed it I wouldn't have had such a hard time making everything line up when I fixed it (I'm *still* not happy with how it looks now :/).

Comment: More interesting, the previous (controversial due to supposed advertising) version of the image was missing the "n".

Comment: That is hilarious. so all along, the MOD-Team was having a fit about the "advertising" and "spam" when we all missed a typo that should have been obvious! lol!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ooops! That was a bad typo

It is now fixed, and all the old images updated!

[image]

There we go!

Comment: You'll never be able to forget :-) http://i.stack.imgur.com/mh7TN.png

Comment: With or without typo... Thanks @GiantCowFilms for creating the http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ it has certainly made this site a lot more useful!

Comment: @cegaton You are welcome, it was much fun, thanks for the kind words!

Comment: I still think "dowload" should be a hidden bonus feature. Like, if you type it into the URL you get some "Easter egg" or something. ...Shoot, the URLs use a different schema, no way to implement that.

Comment: @Mentalist If you want Easter eggs, take a look at the bottom of my profile.

Answer (score 5):

This service is generously hosted/provided to the community by [GiantCowFilms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/3127/giantcowfilms?tab=profile), send all blame his way ;). You can give him a nudge in our main chatroom to update the image.