# Minor typos found on blend-exchange form

Tags: discussion, blend-exchange

Sorry if I could seem nitpicking (I could probably be), but just noted that the submission form has some minor typos in a couple of texts/placeholders, just in case someone wish to correct those. Not that important, obviously, I guess no one ever noticed this before.

[image]

Comment: I need to dowload the blend for to help my queston :)

Comment: For to help sounds lich an an archaicism to me; not that it shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Don't worry about that, it shouldn't at all take long for @GiantCowFilms to fix it.

Comment: No, I'm quite glad you pointed this out. I am [notorious](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/931/some-users-appends-blend-files-with-wrong-dowload-linked-image) for making typos.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I know that other issue, too... :)

Comment: @X-27 that is not constructive. Please edit your comment.

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite I actually liked that comment, but he can't edit the comment, anyway, that is possible only within 5 minutes...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Fixed!

All changes should now be visible on the site.

P.S.

If anyone feels like giving the copy on blend-exchange a good run down and making changes (there are awkward sentences as well as typos), [the repo is available here](https://github.com/GiantCowFilms/Blend-Exchange/tree/master/Blend-exchangePHP). Changes can be made to files directly on github (no need to mess with git command line).